# maxima: isolate the denominator of a ratio

Tags: maxima

When solving a certain system of equations, I have the following:

```
(%i6) cp[1][1];
               3       3       2    3   3         3        2    2         2
(%o6) a11 = (p2  ((2 p1  - 4 p1 ) p3  q4  + (10 p1  - 26 p1 ) p3  p4 q3 q4
         3        2       2   2           3       2    3   3
 + (10 p1  - 26 p1 ) p3 p4  q3  q4 + (2 p1  - 4 p1 ) p4  q3 )
         3        2           3      2         2            2   2
 + q1 (p2  ((10 p1  - 6 p1) p3  p4 q4  + (32 p1  - 22 p1) p3  p4  q3 q4
         2              3   2      2         2   3      2
 + (10 p1  - 6 p1) p3 p4  q3 ) + p2  ((- 4 p1  p3  p4 q4 )
        2   2   2             2      3   2
 - 16 p1  p3  p4  q3 q4 - 4 p1  p3 p4  q3 )
         2        2            3   2            2            2   3
 + q2 (p2  ((32 p1  - 17 p1) p3  p4  q4 + (32 p1  - 17 p1) p3  p4  q3)
               2   3   2            2   2   3
 + p2 ((- 11 p1  p3  p4  q4) - 11 p1  p3  p4  q3))
          2              3   3       2   3   3    2
 + ((10 p1  - 2 p1) p2 p3  p4  - 3 p1  p3  p4 ) q2 )
     2           3        2    3      2         3         2    2   2
 + p2  q2 ((10 p1  - 22 p1 ) p3  p4 q4  + (32 p1  - 110 p1 ) p3  p4  q3 q4
         3        2       3   2      2    3
 + (10 p1  - 22 p1 ) p3 p4  q3 ) + q1  (p2
                3   2                    2   3
 ((10 p1 - 2) p3  p4  q4 + (10 p1 - 2) p3  p4  q3)
     2            3   2              2   3
 + p2  ((- 5 p1 p3  p4  q4) - 5 p1 p3  p4  q3)
                  2   3   3             3   3
 + ((10 p1 - 1) p2  p3  p4  - 4 p1 p2 p3  p4 ) q2)
        2        3        2    3   2            3        2    2   3
 + p2 q2  ((10 p1  - 15 p1 ) p3  p4  q4 + (10 p1  - 15 p1 ) p3  p4  q3)
        3     2    3   3   3        3   3   3     2   3   3    3
 + (2 p1  - p1 ) p3  p4  q2  + (2 p2  p3  p4  - p2  p3  p4 ) q1 )
    3      3   3   3        3   2         2        3      2   2
/(p2  (2 p1  p3  q4  + 10 p1  p3  p4 q3 q4  + 10 p1  p3 p4  q3  q4
       3   3   3          3       2   3      2        2   2   2
 + 2 p1  p4  q3 ) + q1 (p2  (10 p1  p3  p4 q4  + 32 p1  p3  p4  q3 q4
        2      3   2      2          2   3   2           2   2   3
 + 10 p1  p3 p4  q3 ) + p2  q2 (32 p1  p3  p4  q4 + 32 p1  p3  p4  q3)
        2      3   3   2      2          3   3      2        3   2   2
 + 10 p1  p2 p3  p4  q2 ) + p2  q2 (10 p1  p3  p4 q4  + 32 p1  p3  p4  q3 q4
        3      3   2      2    3          3   2              2   3
 + 10 p1  p3 p4  q3 ) + q1  (p2  (10 p1 p3  p4  q4 + 10 p1 p3  p4  q3)
           2   3   3            2       3   3   2           3   2   3
 + 10 p1 p2  p3  p4  q2) + p2 q2  (10 p1  p3  p4  q4 + 10 p1  p3  p4  q3)
       3   3   3   3       3   3   3   3
 + 2 p1  p3  p4  q2  + 2 p2  p3  p4  q1 )
```

I would like to isolate the denominator of `a11` with the purpose of e.g. factorizing it. How would one go about it?
`cp` is the solution to a linear system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the functions `num` and `denom` to get the numerator and denominator of a ratio, respectively.

In order to get the ratio in %o6 as you showed it, try `rhs(%o6)`.